# Register device for AWS device farm

Tags: ios, aws-device-farm

I will be using the AWS device farm for my iOS app related testing. Please let me know that in this case do I need to register a device using XCode. If yes, what will be the difference in the process for the same compared to registering using an actual iOS device?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add a device to your provisioning profile. AWS Device Farm resigns your app before installing it onto their devices.

More information can be found at https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/faq/ under "Q: Do you modify my app?"

Scott